# Upload a realm to bitnami/keycloak on helm install

Tags: kubernetes, helm, kubernetes-helm, keycloak

I'm trying to upload a realm to my keycloak deployment via helm using the **bitnami/keycloak** chart.

Here's my `values.yaml` override file that I'm just using to test:

```
keycloakConfigCli:
  enabled: true
  configuration:
    realm1.yaml: |
      realm: test
      clients: []
```

Here's my helm command:
`helm upgrade keycloak bitnami/keycloak --version 13.0.3 -f ~/***/values.yaml --namespace test --debug --install`

I get a bunch of errors:

```
history.go:56: [debug] getting history for release keycloak
Release "keycloak" does not exist. Installing it now.
install.go:178: [debug] Original chart version: "13.0.3"
install.go:195: [debug] CHART PATH: /home/ubuntu/.cache/helm/repository/keycloak-13.0.3.tgz

client.go:128: [debug] creating 11 resource(s)
client.go:299: [debug] Starting delete for "keycloak-keycloak-config-cli" Job
client.go:128: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:529: [debug] Watching for changes to Job keycloak-keycloak-config-cli with timeout of 5m0s
client.go:557: [debug] Add/Modify event for keycloak-keycloak-config-cli: ADDED
client.go:596: [debug] keycloak-keycloak-config-cli: Jobs active: 0, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:557: [debug] Add/Modify event for keycloak-keycloak-config-cli: MODIFIED
client.go:596: [debug] keycloak-keycloak-config-cli: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:557: [debug] Add/Modify event for keycloak-keycloak-config-cli: MODIFIED
client.go:596: [debug] keycloak-keycloak-config-cli: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:557: [debug] Add/Modify event for keycloak-keycloak-config-cli: MODIFIED
client.go:596: [debug] keycloak-keycloak-config-cli: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:557: [debug] Add/Modify event for keycloak-keycloak-config-cli: MODIFIED
client.go:596: [debug] keycloak-keycloak-config-cli: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 1, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:557: [debug] Add/Modify event for keycloak-keycloak-config-cli: MODIFIED
client.go:596: [debug] keycloak-keycloak-config-cli: Jobs active: 0, jobs failed: 1, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:557: [debug] Add/Modify event for keycloak-keycloak-config-cli: MODIFIED
Error: failed post-install: job failed: BackoffLimitExceeded
helm.go:84: [debug] failed post-install: job failed: BackoffLimitExceeded
```

I've read over the [docs](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/keycloak#keycloak-config-cli-parameters) several times... even [reviewed related issues on their GitHub](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/14184).

**What am I doing wrong here and how can I import a realm on startup?**